# Update all values within date range starting from the most recent record for selected User_ID

Tags: php, mysql

I need to update all records from a special date and above with a value. I use the bellow query but it adds the new value to all starting dates. The value must be added only beggining from selected date up to latest. Thank U all.

```
datepicker    ammount
------------------------
2009-08-25    75 (+ 30)
2009-07-01    100 (+ 30)
2009-07-02    120 (+ 30) <-- Need to start adding new value (difference: 30) from here, up to the latest date.
2009-07-02    320
2009-07-02    100  

// MY UPDATE QUERY
------------------------
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mytable 
SET ammount = ammount + '$_POST[difference]' 
WHERE Supplier_id = '$_POST[Supplier_id]' 
AND datepicker BETWEEN '". $_POST['datepicker']."' 
AND CAST(now() AS DATE)
AND DateStamp = (select MAX(DateStamp) 
    FROM mytable  
    WHERE Supplier_id='" .$_POST['Supplier_id'] ."' 
    AND datepicker='" . $_POST['datepicker'] . "')
    ");
```

I can SELECT of above search with following query, but not update. What i'm doing wrong??

```
// THE SELECT QUERY:

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * 
FROM mytable  
WHERE Supplier_id='$_POST[Supplier_id]' 
AND datepicker = '" . $_POST['datepicker'] . "' 
AND DateStamp = (select MAX(DateStamp) 
    FROM mytable  
    WHERE Supplier_id='" .$_POST['Supplier_id'] ."' 
    AND datepicker='" . $_POST['datepicker'] . "') ");
```

Comment: Can we see the data in $_POST['datepicker']? It's likely not being recognized as a date.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you might have a problem in your datepicker, it's also generally unsafe to directly drop post data into a query, so I would recommend doing some data sanitization as this will also help you check to see what your query is before you submit it, like the following:

```
 $difference = (int)$_POST[difference]; //Do some better sanitization here
 $supplierId = (int)$_POST[Supplier_id]; //Do some better sanitization here
 $datepicker = $_POST['datepicker']; //Do some better sanitization here

 $query = "UPDATE mytable " .
 "SET ammount = ammount + $difference  " .
 "WHERE Supplier_id = '$supplierId' " .
 "AND datepicker BETWEEN '$datepicker' AND CAST(now() AS DATE)";

 print $query;
 mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

That will help you see if your query is what you expect it to be.  You can also just generally run select statements instead of update statements to get your where clauses selecting the correct rows in your table data, at which point you can convert the query to an Update query.

Comment: Yes it is true, but my query works OK when it adds the new value (difference), the only thing is how to select the MAX datepicker of a date selected.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, if you're saying you want the max amount for a given day you would need to group by datepicker and then do select max(amount)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. As i mention in my description i need to add a standard ammount to all records starting from a selected date up to now. But in the same starting date there are 3-4 records already. How can i pick up the most recent of this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_POST['datepicker']);

mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE mytable SET ammount = ammount + '$_POST[difference]' WHERE Supplier_id = '$_POST[Supplier_id]' AND datepicker BETWEEN '". $from_date ."' AND CAST(now() AS DATE)");
```

Edit:

strtotime() is pretty good at converting a string to time, and date() will help get your date into the proper format for a mysql date field.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Sorry, my comment is here : I didn't mention that i already use the $datepicker=date("Y-m-d",strtotime($date)); above of my query